# How to re-render partial of model in backbone?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, model, rerender

I have a answers list like below:

[image]

each list item is a backbone model.

```
{
  title: 'answer title...',
  content: 'answer content...',
  voteStatus: 'up'
}
```

When I click up-vote or down-vote, The model's `voteStatus` will be change, and this answer item be re-render.

If there have a picture in answer's content, the picture will be re-render too, But this is not what I want.

How could I just re-render the vote button when I just change `voteStatus`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a subview inside your `AnswerView` that is only responsible for rendering the voting arrows, `VotingArrowsView`. You would initialize this subview inside the `initialize` function of `AnswerView` and then prepend the subview's `el` to the parent view's `el` when `render`ing the parent view:

```
var AnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    this.template = _.template($('#answerTmpl').html());
    this.votingArrowsView = new VotingArrowsView({ model: this.model });
    ...
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.prepend(this.votingArrowsView.render().el);
    return this;
  },
  ...
});

var VotingArrowsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    this.template = _.template($('#votingArrowsTmpl').html());
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:voteStatus', this.render);
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: But I have another question, I think i could move voteButton's click events(click voteUp and voteDown) frome `AnswerView` to `VotingArrowsView`.  when I do this and click the button, it's not work. It seems like the event listening is broken. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I use `this.delegateEvents();` in `VotingArrowsView` when `render`. All done!  thanks :)

Comment: shouldn't there be `var AnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({` instead of `var AnswerView = Backbone.Model.extend({` ?